# Writing a more strongly typed interpreter

Tags: haskell, types, lambda-calculus, typed-lambda-calculus

I have the following numerical expression interpreter (simplified example)

```hs
data Node x
  = Symbol String -- A parsed word coming from Python: syntactic category, feature list, source text
  | Branches x x
  deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

type SyntaxTree = Fix Node

-- here's the type of denotations
data Meaning
  = Number Double
  | BinaryOperator (Double -> Double -> Double)
  | UnaryOperator (Double -> Double)

-- this is a catamorphism
simpleInterpret :: SyntaxTree -> Meaning
simpleInterpret = Fold.cata simpleLexicon

simpleLexicon :: Node Meaning -> Meaning
simpleLexicon = \case
  Symbol "0" -> Number 0
  Symbol "1" -> Number 1
  Symbol "/" -> BinaryOperator (/)
  Branches (BinaryOperator bop) (Number s) -> UnaryOperator (bop s)
  Branches (Number s) (BinaryOperator bop) -> UnaryOperator (bop s)
  Branches (UnaryOperator uop) (Number s) -> Number (uop s)
  Branches (Number s) (UnaryOperator uop) -> Number (uop s)
  _ -> error "not handled"
```

It would be nice if I didn't have to introduce this ungainly `Meaning` type and ensuing rules to combine a `Meaning` on a left branch with a `Meaning` on a right branch. In the real problem, I'm working on, of which this is a simplified example, there need to be more constructors for `Meaning` and it gets to be awkward. Intuitively, I just want my code to know that if the left branch thing is of type `a` and the right branch thing is of type `a->b`, then the result should be of type `b`.

Is there a good technique for doing this, perhaps with fancier type-level machinery? I suppose what I really want is for `Meaning` to be the type of simply-typed lambda calculus expressions, so perhaps the answer is to embed the simply-typed lambda calculus?

Comment: Okay, `Branches` takes an `a -> b` and an `a` and makes a `b`. What does `Symbol` take and make?

Comment: You might like [GADTs in Action](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring15/lectures/11-stlc.html).

Comment: Yep, that looks super relevant, thank you!

Comment: Follow up question: if I were to use this, I'm assuming I'd replace what I called `Meaning` above with `Expr` with e.g. `TInt` as one of the base types.  But supposing I want to represent arbitrary functions, e.g. of type `Int -> Int -> Int` as `Expr`s using the `Lambda` constructor: will I have to explicitly have to add constructors for those functions in my `Bop` type? Or is there a way to lift arbitrary functions into this STLC?

Comment: There's enough hypotheticals and substitutions in your follow-up question that I'm not confident I've got it right. Perhaps it would be good to open a fresh SO question with the details of what you want to know?

Comment: OK, sounds good! I can include more info of the actual problem I want to target there, and it might make the question clearer.